# How to delete unwanted objects from video?

Tags: edit-mode

I am a teacher. I have a small video in which three persons are acting. Now, I want to make a new video to show my students, in which only one among the three characters is present in it, I don’t mind if the back ground is different. Can blender do it for me?

Please answer my question,

Thank you
~ Albert

Comment: You can do this in blender (blender is not going to do it for you). It would be helpful to know  more about the scene. Are the actors moving? Is the camera static? Is the actor that will remain ever blocked by the ones you want to delete? There are many ways to do it. Create a mask around each of the actors (possibly motion tracking would help) and use that mask to reveal an image that would act as background.  Make a search for plane tracking. The other option would be to just create some geometry that will be your background and that occludes everything but the actor you want to keep.

Comment: Without more info or without a sense of your understanding of blender is tough to give you one or many alternatives.  Please [edit] your question and give us a sense of the kind of scene you are dealing with.